# Select query using NOT IN in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables `Sales` and `Return`:

**Sales** table:

```
DocNum         ItemCode
101           itemcode1
101           itemcode2
102           itemcode3
102           itemcode2
```

**Return** table:

```
DocNum         ItemCode
101            itemcode1
102-reject     itemcode2
```

Desired output:

```
DocNum         ItemCode
101           itemcode2
102           itemcode3
```

I need to select data from the `Sales` table that does not exist in the `Return` table, using a `NOT IN` condition. I only get records that match `DocNum` column on the two tables, my problem here is user put a word 'reject' on the `Return` table.

Is there a way to to match the `docnum` column in these situation?

Comment: Please show us your desired output.

Comment: what is your existing NOT IN query like ? What is your matching criteria ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve what you want using a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT s.DocNum
FROM Sales s LEFT JOIN Return r
    ON s.DocNum = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-', r.DocNum) > 0
                     THEN SUBSTRING(r.DocNum, 1, CHARINDEX('-', r.DocNum)-1)
                     ELSE r.DocNum
                  END AND
        s.ItemCode = r.ItemCode
WHERE r.DocNum IS NULL
```

By the way, you should rethink your database design and stop putting the word `"reject"` into an id column, which makes querying the table difficult.  Instead, add a new boolean column called `reject` to keep track of this.

Comment: Thanks it works!, And for your suggestion, I cannot do it, This is an old system I don't have the source code to control user input, BTW Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM   Sales s
WHERE  NOT EXISTS
       (
            SELECT *
            FROM   [Return] r
            WHERE  r.DocNum LIKE s.DocNum + '%'
       )
```

Comment: @odlanyer, just add `AND r.ItemCode = s.ItemCode` in the `WHERE` clause (the one inside the `NOT EXISTS`).

Comment: I think your `WHERE` clause might match `102` to `1023-reject`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the question is concerned, the query below should return the expected output, even if the DocNum is set to something like "102/reject" or "102(reject)" or whatever.

```
select a.DocNum, a.ItemCode
from SalesTable a
left join ReturnTable b     on charindex(a.DocNum, b.DocNum) > 0
                                and a.ItemCode = b.ItemCode
where b.DocNum is null
```

However, as far as sensible table design is concerned, allowing DocNum to be updated to 102-reject is a bad practice. This exposes a few design flaws:

- DocNum is a varchar column instead of a more suitable integer column
- Allowing user to manipulate what is obviously a key column may introduce SQL injection risks.
- and what happens when DocNum is updated to "102-101"?